# Spring Boot and initializing a sessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Having a tough time initializing my sessionfacory to run in Springboot. When I "un" autowire my sessionfactory App runs but cannot get info from Mysql. Thanks for any help in advance.

My Main:

```
       @SpringBootApplication
        public class Application {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
              SpringApplication.run(Application.class)
              }
       @Bean
            public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean 
                 sessionFactory(){
           return new 
      HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

MyDAO:

```
@Repository
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Query<Customer> theQuery = session.createQuery("FROM CUSTOMER", Customer.class);

        List<Customer> customers = theQuery.getResultList();

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        return customers;

    }
}
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=springstudent
spring.datasource.password=springstudent
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

My Print Trace:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/ronald/IdeaProjects/springtutorial/target/classes:/Users/ronald/mysql-connector-java-5.1.41/mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.9/logback-classic-1.1.9.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.9/logback-core-1.1.9.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.22/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.22/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/nz/net/ultraq/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/1.4.0/thymeleaf-layout-dialect-1.4.0.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.7/groovy-2.4.7.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.3.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.6/jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.6/jackson-core-2.8.6.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.9.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.21.0-GA/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.40/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/c3p0/c3p0/0.9.1.2/c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.9/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.5.11/tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.5.11/tomcat-juli-8.5.11.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.0.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.11.0.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.13.0.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.22/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring3/3.0.3.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring3-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/2.1.5.RELEASE/thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.0.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/ronald/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.22/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.luv2code.springtutorial.Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.1.RELEASE)

2017-04-15 08:32:43.527  INFO 1423 --- [           main] com.luv2code.springtutorial.Application  : Starting Application on Ronalds-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 1423 (/Users/ronald/IdeaProjects/springtutorial/target/classes started by ronald in /Users/ronald/IdeaProjects/springtutorial)
2017-04-15 08:32:43.531  INFO 1423 --- [           main] com.luv2code.springtutorial.Application  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-04-15 08:32:43.812  INFO 1423 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@564718df: startup date [Sat Apr 15 08:32:43 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-15 08:32:45.186  INFO 1423 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-04-15 08:32:45.264  INFO 1423 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'validator' of type [class org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-04-15 08:32:45.327  INFO 1423 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c4046f63] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-04-15 08:32:45.776  INFO 1423 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-04-15 08:32:45.796  INFO 1423 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-04-15 08:32:45.797  INFO 1423 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-04-15 08:32:45.947  INFO 1423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-04-15 08:32:45.947  INFO 1423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2139 ms
2017-04-15 08:32:46.158  INFO 1423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-04-15 08:32:46.164  INFO 1423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-15 08:32:46.165  INFO 1423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-15 08:32:46.165  INFO 1423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-15 08:32:46.165  INFO 1423 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-15 08:32:46.253  WARN 1423 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory must not be null
2017-04-15 08:32:46.265  INFO 1423 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-04-15 08:32:46.278 ERROR 1423 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at com.luv2code.springtutorial.Application.main(Application.java:11) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:127) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1634) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:220) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:345) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:143) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.setBeanFactory(EntityManagerFactoryAccessor.java:137) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1647) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1615) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.getObject(HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.java:46) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.getObject(HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.java:41) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating HibernateSessionFactory is not necessary when u are using spring boot. Spring boot looks for JPA in classpath and if its available then on its own creates a HIbernateSessionFactory with the properties defined in the application.properties/yml file.

The idea of spring boot is to use convention over configuration. So just define the hibernate properties in properties file and pull the jpa starter in your pom. Spring boot will create the SessionFactory for you. You can directly autowire them and start using.

Remove this code.

```
@Bean public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
    return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is a hibernate properties file required before I add it to my application.properties file?

Comment: No hibernate properties is not required seperately. All u have to need is just jpa properties under the namespace spring.jpa.hibernate which you already have.